# GetLastError() возвращает ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND

Tags: mfc, resources, visual-c++

```
#include "conmat.h"
#include "resource.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <afxwin.h>
#include <atlimage.h>

void main(){    
    CImage bmp;
    bmp.LoadFromResource(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),RES_BMP);

    std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GetModuleHandle(NULL) instead of AfxGetInstanceHandle().
```